# Business class on Iberia / Canadair RJ 1000

Tags: seating, iberia

I plan to travel from Bologna (BLQ) to Madrid (MAD) with [Iberia flight 8783](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByFlight.do?flightNumber=YW8783) later this year.

I can have business class tickets, so I have looked at the airplane scheduled (a Canadair RJ 1000 according to flightstats) and [Seatguru tells me there are no business class seats on that plane](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Iberia/Iberia_Canadair_CRJ1000.php).

So I was wondering, in what exactly consists the business class on this flight? Are those worth the price?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar experience with KLM on a flight from Amsterdam to Budapest; except it was on a 737; which had no special business class seating:

Here is what you can expect in terms of perks for your business class ticket:

1. Priority boarding
2. Priority deplaning of you and your luggage
3. Access to the lounge
4. Bonus miles (vs. economy)
5. Meals (if otherwise not included in the flight)
6. Priority rescheduling (in case flight is delayed or canceled)
7. Free middle seat (the 737 has 3-3 seating, and in business class, the middle seat is not available for reservation). This doesn't apply to the CRJ though, it has 2-2 seating.

As this flight was part of a longer flight, I did not have a choice but to fly on business. If given the chance, I would have flown economy on this leg as I normally fly business for the comfort of the seats.

Answer (score 8):

Some clarifications on @BurhanKhalid's answer, this is specific to Iberia regional jets and not just general Euro business:

Although it is not guaranteed in the 2x2 seating layout, you will probably get an empty seat beside you unless the flight is full.

You'll get complimentary food and drink on board. This is supposed to be plated on proper china with metal cutlery but this is no longer consistent and sometimes you just get something from the economy menu for free. (Economy passengers receive a buy-on-board service.) You should find that the service is more attentive as there is usually one crew member dedicated to the small business class cabin, but obviously this depends on the crew.

The physical seats are the same as in economy class, as is the seat pitch. Sometimes you get a full size pillow but to be honest I don't remember if this happens on the regional jets or just the larger planes.

In theory you have priority boarding before the other passengers, but I doubt it will be enforced at BLQ. You will also have access to the Marconi Business lounge at BLQ. Priority luggage delivery might be included, but it is not something to rely on.

Whether it is "worth it" is a subjective question that depends on your individual circumstances and indeed the price of the flight. Since you are curious you might as well try it and make up your own mind.